# Handling complex html elements with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working with the FirstSpirit CMS. This CMS generates HTML-Pages in a similar way as php does. The code below shows a snippet from a module:

```
<script>
    var elements = {
        start: "$CMS_VALUE(getStartDate)$",
        ende: "$CMS_VALUE(getEndDate)$",
        alwaysVisible: $CMS_VALUE(st_alwaysVisible)$,
        html: [
            $CMS_FOR(element, st_targetContent)$
                {content: $CMS_TRIM(level:4)$
                                '$CMS_VALUE(element)$'}
                                $CMS_IF(!#for.isLast)$,$CMS_END_IF$
                            $CMS_END_TRIM$
            $CMS_END_FOR$
        ]
    }

    targetingContent.push(elements);
</script>
```

As you can see I want to generate a JSON-object which is pushed to the array `targetingContent` which is defined in another place. The object has multiple content-parts stored in `st_targetContent`. In my for-loop I want to take each of these parts and store them in content. My problem is, that each `element` contains complex html-structures (from simple text-image-combination to large image galleries). Here an example:

```
<div class="po-dynamicElement po-element element-invisible" data-divisionid="4" data-divisionname="Industrie" >
    <h1 id="headline_ich_bin_das_industrie">Ich bin das Industrie</h1>
    <div class="section text-image">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mb-4">
                <figure>
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="/fs5preview/preview/522144/media/DE/current/526966/res_wl2bootstrap_1200/background_kfz_710.jpg" title="sdf" alt="dfad" width="1200" height="799" />
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <p><b>Metall</b></p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to put this html-structure in an json-object? I've tried to put the whole string in one line and wrap it in single quotes. This works fine till someone uses single quotes within a text. Also it makes the source code very ugly.

Comment: You can decode it before passing.

Comment: you can use some templating system,, handlebars, mustache, etc.. http://handlebarsjs.com/ and then fill data in loop

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to use a template engine. Plain JavaScript and jQuery is all I can use..

Answer (score 0):

I would first build up the complete structure in the "Java world", i.e. with FirstSpirit templates variables. Then you can convert this into a JSON structure with one call to [`.toJSON()`](https://docs.e-spirit.com/odfs/template-develo/template-syntax/data-types/map/index.html#s46). `.toJSON()` will take care of the quoting.

The content parts can be collected in a list using a `$CMS_FOR$` loop, starting with an empty list and calling the Java method [`.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) in each iteration. To do this, we use `$CMS_SET(void, set_html.add(...))$` in the below code. We are not really setting a variable there, we just want the side effect of `.add` to happen, i.e. append an element to the list.

I am not sure what exactly is in your `st_targetContent`. If it is a container of strings, the following should work. We use this approach heavily in our project. Be aware, however, that I was not able to test the below code because I do not have FirstSpirit installed on my private computer.

```
$CMS_SET(set_html, [])$
$CMS_FOR(for_element, st_targetContent)$
    $CMS_SET(set_content, {
        "content": for_element
    })$
    $CMS_SET(void, set_html.add(set_content))$
$CMS_END_FOR$
$CMS_SET(set_elements, {
    "start": getStartDate,
    "ende": getEndDate,
    "alwaysVisible": st_alwaysVisible,
    "html": set_html
})$
<script>
    var elements = $CMS_VALUE(set_elements.toJSON())$;
    targetingContent.push(elements);
</script>
```